# Remove a range from Rust BTreeMap

Tags: rust

I have a `BTreeMap<f64,_>` and want to leave numbers `x` where `low < x < high`.
However `split_off(k)` cannot control `k` being inclusive or exclusive.

This is a temporary solution with eps:

```
// delete all numbers >= high
let _ = map.split_off(high);

// want to delete all numbers <= low
map = map.split_off(low+1e-8);
```

A correct approach is to delete elements one by one, which I think can take `O(n lg n)`.
Is there a way to use `map.range((Excluded(&low), Excluded(&high)))` and delete the range in `O(lg n)`? It looks like I need `map.erase(range)` or `map.split_off_after(k)`.

Comment: Instead of your `eps` trick, why not use `map = map.split_off(low); map.remove(low);`? This feels less hacky. I don't think you can do better that this.

Comment: That is definitely better. It still takes two O(lg n) ops so probably I have to use other container types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify/partially remove a range from a BTreeMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663342/how-to-modify-partially-remove-a-range-from-a-btreemap)

Comment: [There is a tracking issue about `BTreeMap::drain(range)` which allows exactly for this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81074), but it is unimplemented.